# Meteor js cursor hasNext() and next()?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

## problem

I have a potentially big find query which has to stop once my server "javascript" conditions are met, for instance my server already have documents results to figure out a solution.

The idea here is to iterate a cursor from mongo, hitting mongo "on demand", kinda "streaming", so neither my server or mongo has to fetch all results at once.

## expected behaviour

- query and get cursor ( r = Collection.find() )
- check for next ( r.hasNext() )
- fetch next ( r.next() )
- once my requirements are met, stop ( delete r )

## example code

```
Collection.find().forEach(function(doc) {
  doc = do_my_business( doc );
  if (doc.found) {
    // hey mister cursor, go home and die! don't touch my mongo anymore!
    return false;
  }
});
```

## the real problem

I created another Question which is actually how i end up here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30836586/mongodb-find-near-until-maxdistance-or-at-least-x-records

Comment: The short answer: no. The long answer: maybe you could accomplish this some other way like with a `where` query or an aggregation. It depends on the business logic.

Comment: I'm trying to find a solution "the mongo way", but not much luck so far. I opened a question for that as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30836586/mongodb-find-near-until-maxdistance-or-at-least-x-records

Comment: It seems like you could just do `var count = Collection.find(selectorWithDistance).count()`, then if `count` wasn't sufficient just try again with another distance.

Comment: this way i might end up doing a bunch of queries until i match my requirements, which seems to be less efficient then iterating using a "standard mongodb cursor" ?

Answer (score 1):

A meteor cursor isn't a mongo cursor. Meteor cursors don't have hasNext or next. So, this is really just a question about `forEach`, which is the same as the ES5 `forEach`. So here's what you can do:

1.Fetch all the docs into an array & run a for loop over it, break when criteria is met.

2.Turn a flag when the criteria is met & check at the beginning of the function:

```
if (isHappy) return;
doc = do_my_business( doc );
if (doc.found) isHappy = true;
```

3. Use a try catch loop:

```
foo = {};
try {
  Collection.find().forEach(function(doc) {
    doc = do_my_business( doc );
    if (doc.found) {
      throw foo;
    }
  });
} catch(e) {
  if (e !== foo) {
    throw e;
  }
}
```

4.Forget the forEach garbage & use a `$where` with a `findOne` + (do a `find().limit(1).explain()` so you can see that it won't touch every document.)

5.Store something in your database so you don't have to use javascript on the cursor. Repeating a javascript loop over every doc on the server should be avoided like the plague. Storage is cheap. processing, not so much.

Comment: I don't want to fetch all the documents beforehand, also having server-side logic is a requirement for my solution.

Comment: i could use a mongodb cursor to the same collection and do the trick with mongodb "regular driver". I find curious that most answers i found on the web do "fetch all documents" or use synchronous forEach ( therefore fetching all docs ), maybe i'm missing a point...